# Align to rows from different columns

Tags: html, css, row, multiple-columns

I'm almost a total noob about HTML. If you think the answer was already given somewhere, please tell me! But first, let me explain:

I have a music blog on which I translate Chinese Music. The left side is a Column with the original lyrics and the right side is the column with its translation.

My problem is: I align the rows by simply pressing enter between verses. It works quite fine for the web version, but on the Mobile version, it gets all messed up.

So I thought the obvious: It might definitely exist a code to solve this issue. I actually know a couple of sites that do this just fine. (a Brazilian website called 'Letras Terra', for instance. I'm Brazilian by the way)

I tried inspecting their HTML but couldn't figure out any solution at all.

If you want to have a look by yourself on my Blog just Google this: Baxi YinYue. And then you'll find it.

Here is a snipped from the code for one of the translations:

```html
<div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 1px; width: 43%;">
<div style="text-align: right;">
今天发现你<br />
交了新男朋友<br />
仔细看一看<br />
长得还很像我<br />
<br />
你怎么可以<br />
交了新男朋友<br />
虽然当初是<br />
我先跟你说分手<br />
<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
搭拉搭拉搭<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
<br />
当流下的眼泪<br />
滴在他身体<br />
就已经不再爱我<br />
<br />
为什么我还没有<br />
新女朋友<br />
而你却已经交了<br />
新男朋友<br />
<br />
交往前有没有想到<br />
我会很难过<br />
躺在床上看你照片<br />
眼泪没停过<br />
<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
搭拉搭拉搭<br />
搭拉搭拉<br />
<br />
当流下的眼泪<br />
滴在他身体<br />
就已经不再爱我<br />
<br />
难道你不再爱我<br />
你真的不再爱我<br />
你已经不在<br />
<br />
我没有用 我没有用<br />
没办法给你要的生活<br />
当流下的眼泪<br />
滴在他身体<br />
就已经不再爱我<br />
<br />
你没有错 你没有错<br />
选择了自己要的生活<br />
当流下的眼泪<br />
滴在他身体<br />
就已经不再爱我<br />
<br />
只希望他可以<br />
好好疼妳<br />
陪你走过那些<br />
我无法给你<br />
<br />
难过的时候<br />
他会抱抱妳<br />
还要买妳<br />
愛吃的蛋饼</div>
</div>
<div style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 1px; width: 55%;">
<div style="text-align: left;">
Hoje descobri que você<br />
Arrumou um namorado novo<br />
Olhando minunciosamente<br />
Ele parece bastante comigo<br />
<br />
Como você pode<br />
Arranjar outro namorado?<br />
Sendo que fui eu<br />
Que terminei com você primeiro?<br />
<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
Da-la-da-la-da<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
<br />
Quando as lágrimas<br />
Cairem no corpo dele<br />
Por não me amar mais<br />
<br />
Por que eu ainda não tenho<br />
Uma nova namorada?<br />
E mesmo assim você já<br />
Arranjou um namorado novo<br />
<br />
Antes de arranjar não pensou<br />
Que eu ficaria muito triste?<br />
Deitado na cama vendo sua foto<br />
As lágrimas não param de cair<br />
<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
Da-la-da-la-da<br />
Da-la-da-la<br />
<br />
Quando as lágrimas<br />
Cairem no corpo dele<br />
Por não me amar mais<br />
<br />
Será que você não me ama mais?<br />
Você realmente não me ama mais<br />
Você não está mais<br />
<br />
Eu sou inútil, eu sou inútil<br />
Incapaz de lhe dar a vida que você quer<br />
Quando as lágrimas<br />
Cairem no corpo dele<br />
Por não me amar mais<br />
<br />
Você não errou, você não errou<br />
Em escolher a vida que quer para si<br />
Quando as lágrimas<br />
Cairem no corpo dele<br />
Por não me amar mais<br />
<br />
Só espero que ele<br />
Lhe machuque muito<br />
Que ele te acompanhe naquilo<br />
Que eu não pude lhe dar<br />
<br />
Que quando estiver triste<br />
Ele abrace você<br />
Ou melhor, que lhe compre<br />
O omelete que você ama</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
```

As you can see, even here the rows get misaligned, but on the web version of the blog, they are fine.
I just want to be 100% aligned with a code, so it never gets messed up in any device. 
Thanks!

---- UPDATE
Hans Felix solution is working for mobile devices as I wanted it to, but it makes the post creating process much harder. Here I added an image, so you guys can understand what I mean. The first picture is my original code on the editor, the second is Felix code.

---

The solutions and their problems here explained here on this picture:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution without changing the html, make the line height match the two.

```css
div {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 1px; width: 43%;">
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    今天发现你<br /> 交了新男朋友
    <br /> 仔细看一看
    <br /> 长得还很像我
    <br />
    <br /> 你怎么可以
    <br /> 交了新男朋友
    <br /> 虽然当初是
    <br /> 我先跟你说分手
    <br />
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉搭
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br />
    <br /> 当流下的眼泪
    <br /> 滴在他身体
    <br /> 就已经不再爱我
    <br />
    <br /> 为什么我还没有
    <br /> 新女朋友
    <br /> 而你却已经交了
    <br /> 新男朋友
    <br />
    <br /> 交往前有没有想到
    <br /> 我会很难过
    <br /> 躺在床上看你照片
    <br /> 眼泪没停过
    <br />
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉搭
    <br /> 搭拉搭拉
    <br />
    <br /> 当流下的眼泪
    <br /> 滴在他身体
    <br /> 就已经不再爱我
    <br />
    <br /> 难道你不再爱我
    <br /> 你真的不再爱我
    <br /> 你已经不在
    <br />
    <br /> 我没有用 我没有用<br /> 没办法给你要的生活
    <br /> 当流下的眼泪
    <br /> 滴在他身体
    <br /> 就已经不再爱我
    <br />
    <br /> 你没有错 你没有错<br /> 选择了自己要的生活
    <br /> 当流下的眼泪
    <br /> 滴在他身体
    <br /> 就已经不再爱我
    <br />
    <br /> 只希望他可以
    <br /> 好好疼妳
    <br /> 陪你走过那些
    <br /> 我无法给你
    <br />
    <br /> 难过的时候
    <br /> 他会抱抱妳
    <br /> 还要买妳
    <br /> 愛吃的蛋饼
  </div>
</div>
<div style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 1px; width: 55%;">
  <div style="text-align: left;">
    Hoje descobri que você<br /> Arrumou um namorado novo<br /> Olhando minunciosamente<br /> Ele parece bastante comigo<br />
    <br /> Como você pode<br /> Arranjar outro namorado?<br /> Sendo que fui eu<br /> Que terminei com você primeiro?<br />
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br /> Da-la-da-la-da
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br />
    <br /> Quando as lágrimas<br /> Cairem no corpo dele<br /> Por não me amar mais<br />
    <br /> Por que eu ainda não tenho<br /> Uma nova namorada?<br /> E mesmo assim você já<br /> Arranjou um namorado novo<br />
    <br /> Antes de arranjar não pensou<br /> Que eu ficaria muito triste?<br /> Deitado na cama vendo sua foto<br /> As lágrimas não param de cair<br />
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br /> Da-la-da-la-da
    <br /> Da-la-da-la
    <br />
    <br /> Quando as lágrimas<br /> Cairem no corpo dele<br /> Por não me amar mais<br />
    <br /> Será que você não me ama mais?<br /> Você realmente não me ama mais<br /> Você não está mais<br />
    <br /> Eu sou inútil, eu sou inútil<br /> Incapaz de lhe dar a vida que você quer<br /> Quando as lágrimas<br /> Cairem no corpo dele<br /> Por não me amar mais<br />
    <br /> Você não errou, você não errou<br /> Em escolher a vida que quer para si<br /> Quando as lágrimas<br /> Cairem no corpo dele<br /> Por não me amar mais<br />
    <br /> Só espero que ele<br /> Lhe machuque muito<br /> Que ele te acompanhe naquilo<br /> Que eu não pude lhe dar<br />
    <br /> Que quando estiver triste<br /> Ele abrace você<br /> Ou melhor, que lhe compre<br /> O omelete que você ama</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
```

Comment: hey Zohir, thank you for helping me. It helps a big deal for the Desktop version, but on mobile devices, the rows still get unmatched. You can acess throuhttp://bxyytest.blogspot.com/  through a mobile device to check it

Comment: That's because the lines wrap down which pushes everything, instead if wrapping makes it stay in one line and add horizontal scrolling.

Comment: And how do I do it? Can you show me a video tutorial on youtube or something? I'm really a noob about HTML and CSS. My main issue is the verses getting misaligned on mobile devices. Felix solution worked for mobile devices, but made the post creating process very hard. I posted a picture so you guys can see.

Comment: I had to remove floats they will cause overlap if screen is too narrow, Also i had to put up a wrapper which you can remove but copy the css from it to the wrapper you insert the html into https://jsfiddle.net/a2rk8tep/1/  *As this isn't part of the question i will not update the answer.*

Comment: Zohir, I see it works great for the Desktop version, but on my phone it gets all messed up. I'm uploading a picture of it.

Comment: I uploaded an image with printscreens and explanations of my problem.

Comment: Your solution seems good because the post creating process still easily doable, but it doesn't work properly on the mobile version, the lines get messed up. What should I do?

Comment: You code without any changes works, the reason they mess up is because long lines wrap down to the next line and they push everything down, You'll have to set `white-space:nowrap;overflow:auto` to the div holding the text.

Comment: Yes, but by doing that it still gets misaligned on a mobile phone as you can see on the image I posted

Comment: It doesn't it can't, I tested the code snippet i sent you and it works fine on both mobile and desktop

Comment: I actually applied your code to a test post at http://bxyytest.blogspot.com/2020/04/zahir-test.html if you acess it from a mobile phone you'll see that the left column (the original lyrics) get all pushed left by the right column

Comment: Yes because there's no wrapping and the widest of the two will push the other

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to happen. I want the left side to match the right side.

Comment: Change `flex:1 0 0` to `flex:1 0 50%`

Comment: wow, that's quite a change! Even though the user will have to slide to the side to read all the verses. It's good enough for now! Thank you! I wanted the text to break itself and still match the left side, but compared to before it's hundred times better

Comment: Yeah thats exactly the idea, we replace text wrapping with scroll so everything stay aligned, if you want to keep line breaks a change in layout is necessary.

Comment: Now I noticed that on the web version for some reason unknown to me lyrics are misaligned with the post box. It's far to the right when it should be in the center

Comment: I posted my code and yours within a complete post. You can see that with your code the lyrics go to the right a lot. I don't understand why, everything is defined as "auto"

Comment: The code i gave you works in both screen sizes heck on any size, there must be something interfering in your website.

Comment: Definitely. Anyway, I'll use it for now. You helped a lot. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Need to change the structure. put together both language. e.g.:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.chinese {
  flex: 1 50%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.english {
  flex: 1 50%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="chinese">
    今天发现你
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    Hoje descobri que você
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="chinese">
    交了新男朋友
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    Arrumou um namorado novo
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="chinese">
    仔细看一看
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    Olhando minunciosamente
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="chinese">
    长得还很像我
  </div>
  <div class="english">
    Ele parece bastante comigo
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to make ease to create in blogger editor, another option is create an table:

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
          今天发现你</div>
      </td>
      <td>Hoje descobri que você</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
          交了新男朋友</div>
      </td>
      <td>Arrumou um namorado novo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
          仔细看一看</div>
      </td>
      <td>Olhando minunciosamente</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="text-align: right;">
          长得还很像我</div>
      </td>
      <td>Ele parece bastante comigo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, I added two divs more

Comment: Hans, thank you for helping me. But it didn't solve the problem, because it shows as a single column on mobile devices. You can access https://bxyytest.blogspot.com/ and see how it looks. It's your name on the title.

Comment: Hans, SORRY SORRY SORRY

Comment: Your solution actually worked. The problem was my template for mobile devices. I fixed it. But my problem now is: Will I have to put a <div> when I write the verse? Is there some way to do it automatically? Because with the code I used it was automatic

Comment: You see, when I used my old code, on the blogger text editor it showed me two columns (the right with the original lyrics and the left with the translation). So I only had to copy and paste the new lyrics I wanted to translate and them translate it on the right column. It was easy to do.

Comment: The problem is both columns are not linked, the main idea to linked is to put together inside a element(like div) to get the visual style you are required

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand. Anyway, I added an image of the editor so you can understand better what I mean.

Comment: I uploaded an image with printscreens and explanations of my problem.